# Python Telegram API. Счетчик inline кнопки

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Логика кода. Юзер пишет боту текст, бот проверяет по id разрешено ли ему писать, если да, то отправляет это сообщение с двумя кнопками (like/dislike) в канал, по нажатию кнопок выходит вверху всплывающее уведомление. Вопрос как написать счетчик для этих кнопок?

```
from telebot import TeleBot, types
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="bot.log", level=logging.DEBUG)

bot = TeleBot('id') #бот который будет пересылать наши сообщений в канал
bot.delete_webhook()
chatID = '@blablabla' #канал в который бот будет пересылать наши сообщения
users = [123456789] #список id которым разрешено писать боту (через запятую вроде)

#Проверка по id, чтобы левых бот посылал подальше
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id not in users)
def some(message):
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Закрыто!")

#Обработчик нажатий кнопок
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == "up":
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False, text="Good!")
    elif call.data == "down":
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False, text="Bad!")

#Обработчик текста
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def checkbot_text(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btnUp = types.InlineKeyboardButton(str("") + "0", callback_data="up")
    btnDown = types.InlineKeyboardButton(str("") + "0", callback_data="down")
    keyboard.add(btnUp, btnDown)
    bot.send_message(chatID, message.text, reply_markup=keyboard)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == "up":
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False, text="Good!")

        x = str(int(call.message.json['reply_markup']['inline_keyboard'][0][0]['text'][1:]) + 1)
        y = str(int(call.message.json['reply_markup']['inline_keyboard'][0][1]['text'][1:]))
        
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btnUp = types.InlineKeyboardButton(str("") + x, callback_data="up")
        btnDown = types.InlineKeyboardButton(str("") + y, callback_data="down")
        keyboard.add(btnUp, btnDown)

        bot.edit_message_text(call.message.text, call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup = keyboard)
        
    elif call.data == "down":
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False, text="Bad!")

        x = str(int(call.message.json['reply_markup']['inline_keyboard'][0][0]['text'][1:]))
        y = str(int(call.message.json['reply_markup']['inline_keyboard'][0][1]['text'][1:]) + 1)
        
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btnUp = types.InlineKeyboardButton(str("") + x, callback_data="up")
        btnDown = types.InlineKeyboardButton(str("") + y, callback_data="down")
        keyboard.add(btnUp, btnDown)

        bot.edit_message_text(call.message.text, call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup = keyboard)
```

Comment: y = str(int(call.message.json['reply_markup']['inline_keyboard'][1][0]['text'][1:]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Была небольшая ошибка в индексации, проверьте еще раз.

Comment: Kuchizu да теперь работает, а не знаете, как например запретить повторное нажатие, или если нажать на кнопку повторно, то счетчик уменьшился в обратную сторону?

Comment: Тогда уже нужно будет делать глобальные списки и оттуда уже проверять на наличие айди, если айди нету - увеличивать счетчик а если есть уменьшить, но проблема в том что эти списки будут очищаться после каждого перезапуска бота. Лучшим решением является создание бд например Sqlite отлично подойдёт для этого.

Comment: Kuchizu, спасибо, вы очень помогли, будем дальше разбираться.